# Excel workbook import errors

Tags: c#, excel, file-io

I'm working on a Jeopardy application for some practice, and I'm having trouble understanding why I am getting this error. I've narrowed it down to what I believe the issue is, but for now, here's my code...

```
        if (questionPath != "")
        {
            Excel.Application myapp = new Excel.Application();

            Excel.Workbook wb = myapp.Workbooks.Open(questionPath);

            Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            var cell = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1];

            MessageBox.Show(cell.Value);
        }
```

Basically, sets up a new Excel, pulls in the workbook, gets the first sheet, and then looks at whatever cell I tell it to look at and displays the value (like I said, just testing/playing around).

However, if the value in cell A1 is an integer, I get a "RuntimeBinderException was unhandled" error. It says that

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments"
```

However if the value is a STRING, then it works fine. I've tried using Cell.ToString(), which obviously just gives the cell as a COM. I've tried using Cell.Value.ToString, which doesn't exist.... Looking at the intellisense it says that the value IS actually being read in (I used '11' as the value).

Also, I noticed that if I ran my code below, and then tried to open up the Excel to edit it, it tells me that the Excel is locked for editting by myself. I'm guessing I need to close the connection string, but I can't figure out where to do that.

Would I close myapp, or wb, or sheet? I tried a variety of *_*.Close()'s and other things I thought seemed obvious, but nada. Any tips on this as well?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else reading this, 6 years later ...

I would recommend against using `ToSting()` if there is a possibility of `null` data.

`Convert.ToString()` handles null, while `ToString()` doesn't.

In the above scenario, this:

```
var temp = cell.Value.ToString();
```

Would be much safer being this:

```
var temp = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
```

That way, it can deal with any `null` data, unlike `ToString()`.

Comment: The project is long since abandoned, but I appreciate the information!

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the reason it was doing that... it's pulling in an integer. Duh. I guess you can't use Cell.Value.ToString(); in the MessageBox.Show event, so here's what I ended up needing to do, and it worked perfectly.

```
    if (questionPath != "")
    {
        Excel.Application myapp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = myapp.Workbooks.Open(questionPath);
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        var cell = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[1, 1];
        var temp = cell.Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(temp);
    }
```

Thanks for your help! I don't seem to be getting any issues with the Excel being locked to read-only, but I didn't change anything for that either... Assuming it was user error